# How to sum only rows of table after another column equals a certain value in a grouping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that looks like the below for each id.  I want to sort by datetime and sum everything after the last del event.  If I am looking at a single id, I can find the date of the last del and then just sum everything with a later date, but I have to do this for thousands of events so want to do a groupby function.  How can I achieve this?  My code for a single id, which produces the correct answer of 8 is

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'])
last_idx = df.where(df.Event == 'del').last_valid_index()
df[df.datetime > a._get_value(last_idx, 'datetime')].Number.sum()
```

| Event | Number | datetime | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| add | 10 | 1/1/22 | 1 |
| del | 0 | 1/2/22 | 1 |
| add | 12 | 1/4/22 | 1 |
| del | 0 | 1/5/22 | 1 |
| add | 12 | 1/6/22 | 1 |
| add | 2 | 1/15/22 | 1 |
| sub | -6 | 1/16/22 | 1 |
| add | 10 | 1/1/22 | 2 |
| del | 0 | 1/2/22 | 2 |
| add | 12 | 1/4/22 | 2 |
| del | 0 | 1/5/22 | 2 |
| add | 12 | 1/6/22 | 2 |
| add | 2 | 1/15/22 | 2 |
| sub | -6 | 1/16/22 | 2 |

Comment: There is no ID in your input. Can you provide the reproducible input as DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming such an input:

```
    group Event  Number datetime
0       1   add      10   1/1/22
1       1   del       0   1/2/22
2       1   add      12   1/4/22
3       1   del       0   1/5/22
4       1   add      12   1/6/22 # to keep
5       1   add       2  1/15/22 #
6       1   sub      -6  1/16/22 #
7       2   add      10   1/1/22
8       2   del       0   1/2/22
9       2   add      12   1/4/22
10      2   del       0   1/5/22
11      2   add       1   1/6/22 # to keep 
12      2   add       2  1/15/22 #
13      2   sub       3  1/16/22 #
```

Use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a reverse [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) for the selection, then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('group')
         .apply(lambda g: g.loc[g.loc[::-1, 'Event'].ne('del').cummin(),
                               'Number'].sum())
      )
```

Output:

```
group
1    8    # 12+2-6
2    6    #  1+2+3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, I came up with my own solution (below), but yours is much prettier

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort the dataframe by id and datetime.
2. Find the last index of 'del' event for each id.
3. Use the groupby function to group the data by id and apply a custom function to sum the Number values after the last 'del' event for each id.

Here's the code to achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
data = {'Event': ['add', 'del', 'add', 'del', 'add', 'add', 'sub', 'add', 'del', 'add', 'del', 'add', 'add', 'sub'],
        'Number': [10, 0, 12, 0, 12, 2, -6, 10, 0, 12, 0, 12, 2, -6],
        'datetime': ['1/1/22', '1/2/22', '1/4/22', '1/5/22', '1/6/22', '1/15/22', '1/16/22', '1/1/22', '1/2/22', '1/4/22', '1/5/22', '1/6/22', '1/15/22', '1/16/22'],
        'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# sort the dataframe by id and datetime
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'])

# define a function to sum the Number values after the last 'del' event
def sum_after_last_del(group):
    last_idx = group.where(group.Event == 'del').last_valid_index()
    return group[group.index > last_idx].Number.sum()

# group the data by id and apply the sum_after_last_del function
result = df.groupby('id').apply(sum_after_last_del)

# print the result
print(result)
```

This will give you the sum of Number values after the last 'del' event for each id.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that works, but is not very pretty is

```
b = df.sort_values(['id', 'datetime'])]
last_dels = b[b.event == 'det'].groupby(['id'], as_index = False).agg({'datetime': 'max'}).rename(
    columns = {'date': 'last_del_dte'})
b = b.merge(last_dels, on = ['id'], how = 'left')
b['Number'] = np.where((~b.last_del_dte.isna()) & (b.datetime <= b.last_del_dte), 0, b.Number)
b.groupby('id').agg({'Number': 'sum'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def f(x):
    idx = x[x['Event'] == 'del'].last_valid_index()
    x.loc[idx, 'Number'] = x.loc[idx:, 'Number'].sum()
    return x.loc[:idx]

out = df.groupby('id').apply(f).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Event  Number datetime  id
0    add      10   1/1/22   1
1    del       0   1/2/22   1
2    add      12   1/4/22   1
3    del       8   1/5/22   1
7    add      10   1/1/22   2
8    del       0   1/2/22   2
9    add      12   1/4/22   2
10   del       8   1/5/22   2
```